# In R, making packages with functions that are by() and with() compliant

Tags: r, function, grouping, callstack

Working on improving my package [summarytools](https://github.com/dcomtois/summarytools), I'm looking for a way to use the information on each of `by()`'s groups to integrate this info in some function's output. To give a little bit more of a context, the functions in this package print out the dataframe name and variable name(s) being summarized. Functions like `by()` make it difficult because they use generic names such as `dd[x, ]` when slicing the data and feeding it to functions. `substitute()` is thus not an option to get at the x parameter in that case, and the values of the IND variable(s) are also hidden (to a certain level).

To illustrate, in the following example, the group information (c.g. "gender: F" and "smoker: No") is simply printed out with `cat()` when `print.by()` is invoked, using attributes of the object of class "by":

```
dat <- data.frame(gender=rep(c("F","M"),each=15), 
                  smoker=rep(c("Yes", "No")), 
                  someQty=runif(n = 30,min = 0, max = 10))

by(dat$someQty, INDICES = list(gender=dat$gender, smoker=dat$smoker), FUN = mean)

## gender: F
## smoker: No
## [1] 5.560505
## ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
## gender: M
## smoker: No
## [1] 2.568055
## ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
## gender: F
## smoker: Yes
## [1] 4.057938
## ------------------------------------------------------------------------------- 
## gender: M
## smoker: Yes
## [1] 3.416027
```

Now what I need is to get the info for each group *during* the by-group processing (as opposed to recuperating them after the "by" object has been created).

I worked on a solution, but before I repeat a similar work for making functions comply with `with()`, `%>%`, and possibly others... and their combinations, I'm wondering if there might be a simpler approach to this.

Here's what I have so far do deal with `by()`:

```
# Initialise variable in package-specific environment that 
# will help keeping track of the by-processing
myenv <- new.env()
myenv$byInfo <- list()

# Declare some function that will return the `by` variables values
# at each iteration (it's a sort of dummy function that does just that)
myfunc <- function(x) {

  sc <- sys.calls()
  sf <- sys.frames()

  # Find position of by.default() and tapply() in the sys.calls list
  by_pos     <- which(as.character(lapply(sc, head, 1))=="by.default()")
  tapply_pos <- which(as.character(lapply(sc, head, 1))=="tapply()")

  if (length(by_pos) == 1) {

    # check if this is the first "by" iteration
    if(length(myenv$byInfo) == 0) {
      # Standardise the call (adds argument names)    
      by_call <- as.list(pryr::standardise_call(sc[[by_pos]]))

      # Extract the data argument
      by_data <- deparse(by_call$data)

      # Extract the IND variable names
      by_IND <- as.character(by_call$IND)
      by_IND <- by_IND[-which(by_IND=="list")]

      # Get the levels of these IND variables
      by_levels <- sf[[tapply_pos]]$namelist
      levels_df <- expand.grid(by_levels, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

      # Store the info in the package-specific environment
      myenv$byInfo$iter <- 1
      myenv$byInfo$levels_df <- levels_df
      myenv$byInfo$nb_iter <- nrow(levels_df)
    }

    levels_df <- myenv$byInfo$levels_df
    info <- paste(colnames(myenv$byInfo$levels_df), 
                  as.character(myenv$byInfo$levels_df[myenv$byInfo$iter,]), 
                  sep=" = ", collapse = ", ")

    if (myenv$byInfo$iter == myenv$byInfo$nb_iter)
      myenv$byInfo <- list()
    else 
      myenv$byInfo$iter = myenv$byInfo$iter + 1

    return(info)
  }
  return()
}

b <- by(data = dat$someQty, 
        INDICES = list(gender = dat$gender, smoker = dat$smoker), 
        FUN = myfunc)
b[1:4]
## [1] "gender = F, smoker = No"  "gender = M, smoker = No"  
## [3] "gender = F, smoker = Yes" "gender = M, smoker = Yes"
```

So yes, it does give me what I want, but I'd like to know if I'm missing something more straightforward here.

Note: I thought adding a `by=` parameter to some functions and just ignore base R's `by()` altogether but I'd rather use the preexisting base functions people are accustomed to.